# Magento Update & Local Host to Live Server

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-core

I have been working on a Magento site remotely that is now ready to go 'live' (it was worked on remotely as to not make any changes to the live site until it's ready).

I plan on putting all the 'app' / 'media' / 'skin' etc folders back onto the server with the new changes, and will make all the backend changes manually as I want to keep the recent orders and database that has been created.

However I would like to do the update to Magento before doing so. I know that Magento updates often overwrite the 'Core' files. If i'm replacing these with those that I have externally anyway, will it matter? I guess my concern is that the files I upload won't now be compatible with the update that I plan to do.

Comment: You should never edit core files directly! Place them in app/code/local instead. When editing the template files, make sure you don't edit the files in app/design/frontend/base/, but edit your custom theme files instead.

Comment: I haven't made changes to the core, but the previous developer had. Therefore I need to re-upload them.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'd recommend to run a diff with a fresh Magento install of the same version. Then copy all changed files to app/code/local. That way you don't have to overwrite the core files and you can simply first upload the files (app/code/local, app/design .. /skin ..) and then later upgrade the Magento store.

Answer (score 1):

Here first you need to put your work live server as you are planning then update Magento. In this case if you didn't make the changes inside the core file and templates, it will work fine.

If you have changes in code then your changes will not be there after magento update. So you need to work on those changes again and this time remember never make changes inside core files, if you need then use event/observer or override the class.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying to make the site 'live' first before doing the update? I didn't update the 'core' files but I know the previous developer had (I took the site over from someone else).

Comment: yes , make the site live first and make a list of changes which you have in your core files before updating the magento if you know where are the changes because you have to work on those again after magento update

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really sure where the changes are but I will do some investigating. Thanks!